# Как ограничить вращение по оси z?

Tags: unity3d

Мне нужно ограничить вращение по оси z:

```
void RotateToClick()
{
    //позиция мыши в мировых координатах
    mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);



    // Угол между объектами
    angle = Vector2.Angle(Vector2.right, mousePosition - 
    transform.position); //угол между вектором от объекта к мыше и осью х

    // Мгновенное вращение
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 0f, transform.position.y < 
    mousePosition.y ? angle : -angle);
```

Comment: А что надо то? Вы пытаетесь ограничить угол по Z вычисляя его, в добавок проверка отрицательносит угла происходит по координате y.

Comment: мне сделал парень это и этот код работает на ура. обьект поворачивается за мышкой в 2д. мне нужно ограничить на 90, -90 угол по z. для меня вектора это дебри, пока что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void RotateToClick()
{
    //позиция мыши в мировых координатах
    mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);


    transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
    // Угол между объектами
    angle = Vector2.Angle(Vector2.right, mousePosition - 
    transform.position); //угол между вектором от объекта к мыше и осью х

    float z=Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y < 
    mousePosition.y ? angle : -angle,-90,90);

    // Мгновенное вращение
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 0f, z);
```