# Ограничить вращение объекта по одной из осей

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как ограничить вращение объекта по одной из осей, например, на 30 градусов?
Объект двигается зажатой кнопкой мыши.

```cs
void OnMouseDrag()
{
    float rotaion = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, rotaion, Space.Self);
}
```

Comment: `Mathf.Clamp`, не?

Comment: Я не знаю как это в готовый вариант преобразовать

Comment: Очень похожий вопрос уже был тут, почитайте, там есть ответ на ваш вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/792572

Answer (score 2):

```cs
void OnMouseDrag()
{
    float rotaion = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    float rotateAngle = 30,0f;
    Vector3 startRotation;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        float minRotation = startRotation.y - rotateAngle / 2;
        float maxRotation = startRotation.y + rotateAngle / 2;

        Vector3 currentRotation = transform.eulerAngles;
        if(minRotation <= currentRotation.y + rotaion && currentRotation.y + rotaion <= maxRotation)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, rotaion, Space.Self);
        }
    }
}
```

Тут он проверяет - если во время поворота предмет не выйдет за границ поворота, то поворачивается.
Легко и просто :-)

Comment: `transform.eulerAngles` - это высчитываемое на момент вызова свойство, насколько я помню, лучше его кэшировать до if'а. А так да, хороший ответ.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker исправил

Comment: Чуть подправил ваш ответ